# Encrypted accounts backup and restore from 12 word seed

Tags: accounts, encryption, backup

In my wallet I used `ethereumjs-accounts` library to generate and manage accounts. It allows to export and import accounts by json string or zip file. My goal is to add to export/import functionality 12-word-seed encryption. If user want to backup accounts, he should write down generated 12 words (or specify it by himself) and next time to export it, he should reenter this words to decrypt backup file. If something doesn't make sense, please let me know.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what your question is. Could you please add a sentence at the end that clearly states your question?